# Determining optimal block size for blocked matrix multiplication

Tags: c, memory-management, matrix-multiplication, cpu-cache, cache-locality

I am trying to implement blocked (tiled) matrix multiplication on a single processor. I have read the literature on why blocking improves memory performance, but I just wanted to ask how to determine the optimal block size. I need to perform C+A*B where A, B, C are floating-point square matrices of the same dimension. It makes sense that 3 blocks should fit in the cache at once, so should the block size be the cache size divided by 3? Or should the block size be something else?

Finally, can anyone suggest a viable experimental way to determine the optimal block size on the supercomputer I am working with? I am working with GCC C.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your application domain? Weapons? Medical applications? COVID pandemic simulation? Bioinformatics? Finite elements for aircraft simulation?

Comment: I don't know what application domain is

Comment: I improved my comment

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch numerical linear algebra

Comment: But "numerical linear algebra" needs a pencil and paper (and a cheap computer running LaTeX to submit papers to conferences), not a super computer....

Comment: It is part of a plasma physics project

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are already enough implementations of matrix multiplication...

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to implement blocked (tiled) matrix multiplication on a single processor.

Notice that in 2021 most processors are [multi-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor). You might be interested by [POSIX pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). See [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

> I need to perform C+A*B where A, B, C are floating-point square matrices of the same dimension. It makes sense that 3 blocks should fit in the cache at once, so should the block size be the cache size divided by 3?

I am not an expert, but I don't think it is that simple. [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) size is often some power of 2, and you have more than one cache level.

Read about [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and consider using it.

> Finally, can anyone suggest a viable experimental way to determine the optimal block size on the supercomputer I am working with?

I assume that supercomputer runs Linux, and you can compile C code on it with some [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and execute it and [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) it, if it is compiled as a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)). Read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) for details.

Then, after reading [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), you could write some C program (inspired by my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c)) which generates various different *temporary* C files defining C functions using different block sizes, compile -using [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)- some `/tmp/generated1234.c` file with `gcc -O3 -Wall -shared -fPIC /tmp/generated1234.c -o /tmp/generated1234.so`, [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that `"/tmp/generated1234.so"`, [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) these C functions, call them thru pointers, and measure the CPU time of each such plugin.

> I need to perform C+A*B where A, B, C are floating-point square matrices of the same dimension.

Alternatively, some supercomputers have [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)) implementations. You could learn OpenCL (or CUDA) and code them some critical numerical kernel routines in OpenCL (or CUDA), or generate OpenCL (or CUDA) code like you would generate C code.

Of course you want a *recent* GCC, e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in spring 2021. And you probably want to read about all the possible [optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), including [OpenACC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC) and [OpenMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp)

I even guess you might use [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) techniques to find the optimal block size....

Read also about [Open-MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/)

Be aware of `/proc/cpuinfo` documented in [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

You could also contact other super computer users both in your country and elsewhere. [Weather forecasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_forecasting) organizations (in France, [MeteoFrance](https://meteofrance.com/)), or engineers doing [CAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) in various industries (automotive, defense, aerospace, ...) comes to mind. Or [CERN](https://home.cern) (or even my employer [CEA](https://www.cea.fr/)) or people from [ITER](https://www.iter.org/) (in Europe) or [LLNL](https://www.llnl.gov/) (in the USA)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What do you think about measuring L1 cache size in some way and the block size is this divided by 3?

Comment: I have no idea if you can measure the L1 cache size (except by parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`) and I don't know how important it is (w.r.t L2 or L3 caches) in your application

Comment: You can now get cache details [https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cputopology.html](directly via sysfs), e.g. `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/*`.

The `sysconf` function [https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Constants-for-Sysconf.html](provides similar information), but I have to wonder if that's still a valid approach, because at first glance it seems to assume all processors have the same cache details.

For a human-friendly report on cache information, I highly recommend [https://linux.die.net/man/1/lstopo](`lstopo`).